# How to detect Multi-Person Pose Estimation with Mediapipe?

Tags: mediapipe

I want to use mediapipe for pose estimation  for multiple person in video footage. But using mediapipe I cant do it for multiple person. Any solution for this problem?

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Comment: There is a hack using Yolo as preprocessing. https://shawntng.medium.com/multi-person-pose-estimation-with-mediapipe-52e6a60839dd

Answer (score 1):

You can first detect the persons in the image (using HOG features for example, or YOLO) then you extract each of the areas that contain a person and use them as inputs for MediaPipe.

Do not forget to adjust the points reference since MediaPipe output will be related with the tiled segment and not with the original image.

Addittion in December 2023:

You can also check YOLO-NAS that is specifically tuned for these purposes.